# Recovering files using Recuva

Tags: data-recovery

I'm currently using [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) to recover some files from an external NTFS disk.  It finds the files I'm interested in during it's analysis phase (when tools like test-disk fail to find them at all) and reports them as "Not-deleted" and a big green marker to signify 100% chance of recovery.  However when it tries to recover the files I get a "the system could not find the file specified" message.  Is there any easy way to recover non-deleted files off of a disc that I can no longer simply access through explorer?

Answer (score 2):

I have always used this software, if the data is not overwritten or corrupt it will recover it.

http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm

Not free though, just the best.

Comment: GetDataBack has worked the best for me as well.  If your willing (and i feel it pays itself off) to pay the price I say give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

HAve you tried any of [these](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/01/24/top-10-free-data-recovery-software/) others? Also make sure you are not trying to recover the files from the same drive as you are running the program and moving the data to.  That will render the data useless.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Recuva, and I just hit the recover button again and it started working. Check your source and destination drives for permissions issues, stay away from C: drive on Windows.

Here is another [list](http://geekyprojects.com/data-recovery-2/best-data-recovery-software-top-10-list/) of top 10 recovery utilities. I tried Recuva on an SD card and it only recovered something that I deleted long time ago. PhotoRec, however, recovered the files that magically disappeared from my card. Just for comparison: Recuva found some 130 files, while PhotoRec found over 700 (after I moved the executable to another drive on my computer).

In case that site goes down (the author seemed to stop updating the blog), here is her/his top 10:

1. Ddrescue
2. Ubuntu Rescue Remix
3. TestDisk
4. PhotoRec
5. SpinRite
6. HDAT2
7. Recuva
8. Foremost
9. Parted Magic
10. Recover my Files